# Android can we dismiss the notification from any other app after consuming it?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I'm using NotificationListenerService to listen for all the incoming notifications (3rd party apps, messages, mails etc.) from the status bar and reading them aloud. But the problem is that I don't know how to dismiss a notification after reading it from my service. I have gone through notificationManager.cancel(id) but I couldn't get the id for an incoming notification from 3rd party app.

Please let me know if there is a way to dismiss the notification from any app.

Comment: Question: if you have proper BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE permission and right intent you can't read it with StatusBarNotification.getId()?

Comment: I tried notificationManager.cancel(StatusBarNotification.getId()), notificationManager.cancel(StatusBarNotification.getTag(), StatusBarNotification.getId()) and also notificationManager.cancelAll() but they are not clearing the notifications from other applications.

Comment: cancelNotification(pkg, tag, id) worked for me :) This is a method in NotificationListenerService so we dont need notificationManager.

Comment: @Harish Are you sure this worked for removing 3rd party notifications? I was under the impression that was not possible.

Answer (score 1):

cancelNotification() method in the NotificationListenerService class worked for me.

```
            cancelNotification(notificationMessage.packageName,
                notificationMessage.tag, notificationMessage.id);
```

Comment: As of Lollipop that overload of cancelNotification is deprecated.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

Comment: Yep, that overload is deprecated, but you're instead supposed to use the variant that takes in a key (which is a String containing the package, tag, id, uid, etc. and is provided by the StatusBarNotification.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dismiss notifications from other applications. You can however get details about it with the NotificationListenerService.

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification s) {

}
```

But to answer your question, you can only dismiss your own notifications.